# Google Analytics not recording every video progress event

Tags: javascript, video, google-analytics, event-tracking, video-tracking

I have a GA script on my site that tracks video progress. This is what my event tracking code looks like:

...

ga('send', 'event', 'video', '10% completed', 'video name')

...

ga('send', 'event', 'video', '90% completed', 'video name')

When I look on my GA account, the distribution is not what's expected. There should be a lot more
10% completed than 90% completed because some people might drop off before they reach the end of the video. But they are roughly the same (sometimes 90% has more events).

I have verified that my code does send the data at every interval. It seems like only the latest data that is sent is recorded. Is this a bug or is this intended?